# can not use authentication with OAuth 2.0 with JavaMail 1.4

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail

I want to use oauth with IMAP to authenticate to Microsoft Exchange Online in my project. I have log4j that has a dependency of javax.mail 1.4 so in all my project this version is used. To use oauth I have to update javax.mail to 1.6 and I was not successful to do that.

I tried to use javax.mail 1.6 and import it without log4j but it broke my project:

```xml
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to find a version of log4j that uses javax.mail that supports oauth, but I didn't find anything.
Javax.mail is used in other parts of my project, so I don't want to touch those parts if possible.

I'm working on a legacy code, so for me it's important backwards compatibility and to not break my base code.

Comment: If you want to use OAuth 2.0, you have to use JakartaMail 1.6. In general, I think JavaMail/JakartaMail is pretty good at backwards compatibility, so have you actually tried to just upgrade to 1.6 (and make sure the 1.4 version is excluded)? If so, what is the actual problem you run into?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My question is : i have log4j that imports javax.mail 1.4  and i need javax.mail 1.6. Is there any solution to use javax.mail 1.6 without breaking the part of my code where they use javax.mail 1.4? i tried to add the dependency 1.6 in my pom but i had a lot of errors where a lot of jars were not found where i tried to publish the project in tomcat. Or is there any other way to just skip this part and use some library to be able to use oauth with imap to authenticate and read mails from outlook?